# Find and replace with incremental number at the end

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have an xml file with multiple nodes:

```
<member>
    <screen_name>User</screen_name>
    <username>username</username>
</member>
```

What I want tis to find an replace User with User1,User2,User(n) and username with username1,username2, username(n)

Is that possible?

Comment: Or is there an IDE that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply this XSL template to your XML files (there are several command line tools that can do this)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="screen_name/text() | username/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., count(preceding::member) + 1)" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```